# Unable to include json schema in swagger document

Tags: json, swagger, jsonschema

Used to using RAML to define API definitions and my work is investigating switching to using Swagger v3 as it now supports YAML style syntax.

I am looking to migrate a very small RAML document with json schemas and examples to swagger 3, and I am struggling to get the json schema into swagger

I have been using the documentation at https://swagger.io/docs/ and looking at various other blog posts

This is the json schema that I am using and trying to get into swagger

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "analytics": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "date": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "date"
            },
            "submission": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "source": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "model": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "count": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "required": [
            "date",
            "submission",
            "source",
            "model",
            "count"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "analytics"
  ]
}
```

Now looking at the swagger docs and other posts I should be defining schemas using the components tag as it can then be references as $ref: '#/components/schemas/validresponse'

This is what I have created using the swagger docs

```
components:
  schemas:
    validresponse:
      additionalProperties: true
      analytics:
        type: object
        properties: 
          analytics:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
              properties :
                date:
                  type: string
                  format: date
                submission:
                  type: string
                source:
                  type: string
                model:
                  type: string
                count:
                  type: integer
                required: 
                  - date
                  - submission
                  - source
                  - model
                  - count
```

I am using app.swaggerhub.com editor, and I am getting an error

"should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: analytics "
being highlighted on the validresponse line

If i remove the additionalProperties line, then I am still getting the error

I have no other mention of additionalProperty in my swagger doc

I have no idea why this is not working. I hope it is something simple I have done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    validresponse:
      additionalProperties: true
      analytics:
        type: object
        properties: 
          analytics:
            type: array
            ...
```

into

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    validresponse:
      additionalProperties: true
                     # <--- no "analytics:" node here.
      type: object   # <--- "type: object" must be indented same as additionalProperties above
      properties: 
        analytics:
          type: array
          ...
```